# Java how to read and delete contents of a file.

Tags: java

I have a list with about 700 items I need to edit before adding them to my webpage. 
I tried editing each item manually but it became too extensive, and I thought I might use Java instead to read and edit the file since the words that need to be edited have the same beginning and ending in each item.

I thought I would start by looping through the word in Q, save it and when I had the logic working I'd find out how to read the text file and do the same thing again. (I am open for suggestions if there is any other way)
   Here comes the code I put together so far, It was a long time ago I coded in Java so I basically have no skills right now.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CustomizedList
{

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String Ord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a word");
    String resultatOrd ="";

    for(int i = 0; i < Ord.length(); i++)
    {
        if(Ord.charAt(i) == 'y' && Ord.charAt(i) == 'e' && Ord.charAt(i) ==    

's')
        {
            resultatOrd += Ord.charAt(i);
            System.out.println(resultatOrd);
        }   

        else
        System.out.println("Wrong word.");
    }
}
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but the word i input doesnt work logically. 
   There are two words I want to delete from this textfile: YES and NO, both in lower and uppercase.

Comment: As @Christian has said, a character cannot be simultaneously equal to 'y' and 'e' and 's' all at the same time. A character has only one value at a given point in time. However why don;t you try using the equalsIgnoreCase() method in the String class.

Answer (score 5):

Your code cannot be right:

```
if(Ord.charAt(i) == 'y' && Ord.charAt(i) == 'e' && Ord.charAt(i) ==  's')
```

will ***always*** be ***false***

Solution:

```
Ord.toLower().contains("yes")
```

Or (worse but still correct in your case):

```
if(Ord.charAt(i) == 'y' && Ord.charAt(i+1) == 'e' && Ord.charAt(i+2) ==  's')
```

If you are just looking for equality, you can use `equals()`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: how should it be? please do show

Comment: changed my code: Are you looking for eqal strings, or are you searching for a substring?

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` test:

```
if(Ord.charAt(i) == 'y' && Ord.charAt(i) == 'e' && Ord.charAt(i) == 's')
```

Will never be true. You're specifying that the same character must be three different things.

Loot at the method [`String.equalsIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) for a better way of testing for the words that you want.

For instance:

```
if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || word.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
    // do something with word
```

Comment: In other words i am overwriting Ord with a new character each time?

Comment: no not overwriting at all, just testing the same spot for 3 different char values and using `&&`: it can only be one of those, not all three

Comment: Okey thanks. You know how to read a file with this condition? And delete the word in every point it is found!

Comment: figure out how to match words first. Make an example `String` in your code that represents a line from your file, and try to write code that loops over the words in this `String` and match the words that you want to delete. When you get stuck again, post a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, I tried to comment each part to give you an idea of what each line does.
It only works if the "yes" and "no"s are on their own separate lines.

Here's the Java Tutorials link for I/O. I recommend reading it when you have time, lots of good info [Java I/O Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //name of file to read
    File file = new File("filename.txt");

    //BufferedReader allows you to read a file one line at a time
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));   

    //temporary Array for storing each line in the file
    ArrayList<String> fileLines = new ArrayList<String>();

    //iterate over each line in file, and add to fileLines ArrayList
    String temp=null;
    while((temp=in.readLine())!=null){
        fileLines.add(temp);        
    }
    //close the fileReader
    in.close();

    //open the file again for writing(deletes the original file)
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

    //iterate over fileLines, storing each entry in a String called "line"
    //if line is equal to "yes" or "no", do nothing.
    //otherwise write that line the the file
    for(String line : fileLines){
        if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")||line.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
            continue;//skips to next entry in fileLines
        }
        //writes line, if the line wasn't skipped 
        out.write(line);
        out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator")); //newline
    }
    //save the new file 
    out.close();

    }

}
```